# Command line input string type variable vs python string type

Tags: python, linux, string, shell, csv

I have the following python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    airline_id = line[1]
    origin = line[3]
    dest = line[8]
    
    print(airline_id)
    print(type(airline_id))
    test = "WN"
    print(type(test))
    print(airline==test)
```

that out puts:

```
"WN"
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
False
```

Why does it do this? Why are these two not equal? Is there any difference between python string and command-line string?

Comment: Did you copy this correctly? Did you mean print(airline.id) or print(airline_id)? This should have errored with no property 'id' of 'airline'

Comment: oh no, i edited airline_id in the StackOverflow text editor to give more context. I've changed it

Comment: `airline_id` is four characters long because it contains a doublequote character on either end. Parsing `csv` files is not as easy as it sounds. Use the `csv` module instead

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what that_other_guy said in the comments above:

```
echo '2,"WN",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8' | python airline.py 
"WN"
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
False
echo '2,WN,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8' | python airline.py 
WN
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
True
echo 2,WN,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 | python airline.py 
WN
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
True
echo 2,"WN",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 | python airline.py 
WN
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
True
```